# Connection String ASP.NET Classic - (MS SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net, asp, connectionstring

Estou com dificuldades em fazer um site em ASP.NET Classic que sua única função é fazer uma busca no banco de dados MS SQL Server e listar os resultados no website em forma de tabela comum.

Porém toda vez que executo o código o site mostra a seguinte mensagem no site:

"**500 - Internal server error.**
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

[Imagem do console do erro 500 - Internal server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb9MF.png)

Já procurei sobre este problema, porém acredito firmemente que o erro está na Connection String com o banco e/ou alguma configuração/driver deve ser aplicado dentro do banco de dados.

O arquivo web.config dentro da pasta do projeto ASP está correto, testei ele dentro de outro projeto em ASP que estava funcionando e continuou funcionando após a troca. Entretanto aqui está o código do arquivo web.config caso haja dúvidas:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="false" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
    </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <binding maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
    </bindings>
    
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  </system.serviceModel>

    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="tickets.asp" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>```







## ABAIXO É O CÓDIGO EM ASP.NET CLASSIC ##
## BELOW IS THE CODE IN ASP.NET CLASSIC ##








<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
   .style1 {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #0A8C43; font-size:30px;}
   .style2 {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight: bold; color:#FFFFFF}
   .style3 {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; text-align:left}
   .style4 {font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-weight: bold; color:#5C5C5C}
-->
</style>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="">
           
   <table width="100%" border="0">
      <br>
      <tr>
         <td align="center"><span class="style1">Ordens de Manutenção</span></td>
   </table>
   <br>
</form>



<div class="container">


   <div class="row">
   <div  class="d-grid gap-2 col-1 mx-auto"  >
         <div class="row justify-content-end align-self-center">
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success " value="<%=request("reload")%>">Recarregar</button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
         <table width="90%" align="center" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
         </table>
         <br>

          
                          <div ali
                          gn="center">
            <table width="900" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0"></table>


<table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">

<%
end if
      set rstLista=server.createobject("ADODB.recordset")
      rstLista.activeconnection= "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=EM01VS0330; Database=FlexNet; Uid=flexnet_site_ordens; Pwd=senha_do_banco;"

      sql = "select "
      sql = sql & " cast(UC.Attribute_ as varchar(10))     as 'ORDEM', "
      sql = sql & " cast(convert(varchar,RL.StartTime,20)  as varchar(20)) as 'INÍCIO DA PARADA', "
      sql = sql & " cast(convert(varchar,RL.EndTime,20)    as varchar(20)) as 'FIM DA PARADA', "
      sql = sql & " cast(convert(varchar,UC.CreatedOn,20)  as varchar(20)) as 'DATA CRIAÇÃO', "
      sql = sql & " cast(rs.ProductionLine                 as varchar(10)) as 'LINHA', "
      sql = sql & " cast(NT.Description as varchar(30))    as 'DESCRIÇÃO DA ORDEM', "
      sql = sql & " cast(RL.ReasonCode  as varchar (6))    as 'MOTIVO', "
      sql = sql & " cast(TT.Medium      as varchar(20))    as 'DESCRIÇÃO DO MOTIVO', "   
      sql = sql & " cast(EQ.equipment   as varchar(6))     as 'EQPMTO', "
      sql = sql & " cast(TT2.Medium     as varchar(37))    as 'DESCRIÇÃO DO EQUIPAMENTO' "
      sql = sql & " from Unit_Characteristic UC with(nolock) "
      sql = sql & " join resource_labor RL on UC.UnitID = RL.UnitID "
      sql = sql & " join RESOURCE_ RS on RS.ResourceName = RL.ResourceName "
      sql = sql & " join EQUIPMENT EQ on RS.ID = EQ.ResourceID "
      sql = sql & " join NOTE NT on NT.ID = RL.NoteID "
      sql = sql & " join REASON_CODE RC on RC.ReasonCode = RL.ReasonCode "
      sql = sql & " join TEXT_TRANSLATION TT on RC.TextID = TT.TextID "
      sql = sql & " join TEXT_TRANSLATION TT2 on EQ.TextID = TT2.TextID "
      sql = sql & " where UC.Characteristic = 'PM Note' "
      sql = sql & " and UC.CreatedOn >= (select getdate()-2) "
      sql = sql & " and RS.ResourceType = '6' "
      sql = sql & " and TT.LanguageID = '1046' "
      sql = sql & " AND TT2.LanguageID = '1046' "
      sql = sql & " order by UC.CreatedOn desc "


 end if
 rstLista.source=sql
 rstLista.open
 i=0
 ordemAberta=""
     while not rstLista.eof
        if request("reload")<>"" then
         if i=0 then
   
 
%>
           
            
             
<br>
<tr>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Ordem</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Data de Criação</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Início da Parada</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Fim da parada</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Linha</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Desc. Ordem</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Motivo</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Desc. Motivo</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Equipamento</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Desc. Equipamento</span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4"><%=rstLista("ORDEM")%></span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4"><%=rstLista("DT CRIAÇÃO")%></span></td>

                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4"><%=rstLista("INÍCIO DA PARADA")%></span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4"><%=rstLista("FIM DA PARADA")%></span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4"><%=rstLista("LINHA")%></span></td>
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4"><%=rstLista("DESCRIÇÃO DA ORDEM")%></span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4"><%=rstLista("MOTIVO")%></span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4"><%=rstLista("DESCRIÇÃO DO MOTIVO")%></span></td>
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4"><%=rstLista("EQUIPAMENTO")%></span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4"><%=rstLista("DESCRIÇÃO DO EQUIPAMENTO")%></span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>

                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
   
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div  class="d-grid gap-2 col-1 mx-auto"  >
         <div class="row justify-content-end align-self-center">
            <br>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success " value="<%=request("reload")%>">Recarregar</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  <br>
  <br>
        <%
end if


     end if
     if i=5000 then
         response.End()
     end if
       i=i+1
       rstLista.movenext()
 loop
 Response.Write "</ul>"
rstLista.close
%>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-11">
           <div align="center">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
               S3
               <br>
               <tr>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Ordem</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Data de criação</span></td>
          
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Início da parada</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Fim da parada</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Linha</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Descrição</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Motivo</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Desc. Motivo</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Equipamento</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#0A8C43"><span class="style2">Desc. Equipamento</span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
     
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
  
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  bgcolor="#ededed"><span class="style4">.</span></td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
   
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center" ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
                  <td align="center"  ><span class="style4">.</span></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        
</div>
<%
end if
%>
````

Comment: precisamos do erro para poder ter ajudar melhor `500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.` pode ser qualquer coisa. Você tem acesso aos logs da aplicação? Já tentou ir na tab network do navegador para ver o que a requisição está retornando?

Comment: Adicionei a imagem (link na ultima linha do código), porém eu me perguntei a mesma coisa, infelizmente esse erro 500 é muito abrangente, é difícil saber o que especificamente é o problema.

Comment: @weslem-barbose não é uma boa prática, mas no seu `web.config` dentro da tag `system.web` adiciona a chave ` <customErrors mode="Off"/>` e dentro da tag `system.webServer` adiciona a chave `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />`, e vê se agora o erro aparece em tela